# Magento 2 razorpay plugin version - 3.7.5 "Razorpay Error: Razorpay Error: Razorpay paymentId missing for payment verification..."

Tags: magento2, razorpay

I am using Magento 2 api to create order. When COD is used, it works fine but in case of Razorpay it gives error:

> Razorpay Error: Razorpay Error: Razorpay paymentId missing for payment
> verification...

Magento 2 razorpay plugin version used - 3.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face similar issue and found the root cause in the plugin. Sharing the changes I made in the Razorpay plugin file to get it worked.

Magento 2 API where I am getting issue

> POST : '/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/order';

**Solution**
Need to pass additional_data param. Following parameter, I passed to API

```
'additional_data' => array(
   "razorpay_payment_id"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_payment_id'],
   "rzp_payment_id"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_payment_id'],
   "razorpay_signature"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_signature'],
   "rzp_signature"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_signature'],
   "razorpay_order_id"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_order_id'],
   "rzp_order_id"=> $paymethodDetails['razorpay_order_id'],
   "rzp_order_amount"=> $paymethodDetails['rzp_order_amount']),
```

You will find some repetitions of data with different keys.

After this, I got the following error from the plugin file

> Undefined variable: rzp_order_id in /app/code/Razorpay/Magento/Model/PaymentMethod.php on line 371

I made the following change in file **PaymentMethod.php** on line 371

```
 //Original 
 $rzp_order_id = $rzp_order_id; 

 //Updated
 $rzp_order_id = $request['paymentMethod']['additional_data']['rzp_order_id']
```

Post that I got another error on line 375

> Undefined variable: rzpOrderAmount in /app/code/Razorpay/Magento/Model/PaymentMethod.php on line 375

Changed that to

```
 //Updated
 $rzpOrderAmount = $request['paymentMethod']['additional_data']['rzp_order_amount'];
```

**After these changes, I was able to successfully place the order.**